# Why is this returning no elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per trying to run in jsfiddle, I figured this should work, but it is instead returning blanks.

This is the example HTML

```
<table id = "test">
    <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
     <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
     <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I'm just trying to run this code against it.

```
var x = $( "#test").children("tr");
console.log(x);
```

But it is instead returning with nothing in x, rather than all of the tr elements.

Any ideas?

My ultimate goal is to create a function that will iterate through every tr and td in a selected table with jquery, allowing me to "set" div values into them for an online board game. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that

```
$("#test").children("tr");
```

is equivalent to

```
$("#test > tr");
```

but most browsers insert a sorrounding `tbody` if there is none in the table, so `#test > tr` does not match any element, so it is better to use

```
$("#test tr");
```

or if you prefer

```
$("#test").find("tr");
```

Comment: You have a typ. You need to add `#` to the preferred element.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
var x = $( "#test").find("tr");
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why `$( "#test").children("tr")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `.each()`
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nrqx/)**

```
$("#test td").each(function () {
    var x = $(this).text();
    console.log(x);
});
```